# Does rails server have to be running for you to run rake db: actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rake

I've always been confused on how you can executive rake db actions from the terminal. Does it go through rails and then change the db? Or does it go through some environment variable you have on your computer to find the db and then changes it?

I'm asking this because I want to run `bundle exec rake db:drop` but I keep getting

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

even though my `bundle exec rails s` connects me to a server correctly.

Comment: I think it is talking about your database server refusing the connection...

Comment: how do I check on that?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=could+not+connect+to+server%3A+Connection+refused&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Answer (score 1):

You can run the `rake db` commands with the rails server running

The error says there is no connection happening with the database and solution for this is either restart the db server 
(if its postgres)

```
sudo service postgres restart
```

or may be you are providing wrong user name and password in database.yml file(this should match with the db user name and password)

Comment: If this was helpful and relevant you can accept the answer :-)